# Backlighting enamel

Tags: stained-glass

I an interested in enameling on silver. Ideally I would like some of the regions of my piece to be backlit, but I am not sure how to achieve this.

If drill through the silver after the enameling is complete and install the light, then the color of the enamel will not be consistent, because the part over the light will look different than the parts over silver.

One idea was to try to add a layer of cloudy glass below which would diffuse the light and give a consistent background, but I don't know if such a thing exists.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I may not be completely understanding your question.  It seems to me that backlighting, by its very nature, is going to change the vibrancy of the enamel color, and thereby change the color itself.

But, assuming I am understanding your question correctly, what you are attempting to do is called "plique a jour" enameling.  Basically, plique a jour enameling mimics the look of stained glass using silver wire (or a silver sheet with sawn holes) and enamel.  There are lots of videos and tutorials on-line--just google "plique a jour enameling."

I have never done it, but the quick review I did shows that you can lay multiple layers of enamel into the open spaces. I think that you could probably use a clear enamel to fill in your open spaces until the enamel is level with the top of your silver sheet, and then lay a coat of colored enamel over the entire piece, covering the silver and the clear enamel.

Will that accomplish what you are trying to do?